# How to loop objects inside of list in ListView.Builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am doing looping over the list items in ListView.builder

```
List _rBoxes = new List();//declare
```

the data i want to loop is seems like this:

```
{    
    "box_content": {
        "box_1": [
            {
                "id": "9",
                "name": "abc"
            },
            {
                "id": "10",
                "name": "xyz"
            }
        ],
        "box_2": [
            {
                "id": "8",
                "name": "acc"
            }
        ],
        "box_3": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "abc"
            }
        ],
        "box_4": [
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "amno"
            },
            {
                "id": "6",
                "name": "jkl"
            }
        ],
        "box_5": [
            {
                "id": "7",
                "name": "xre"
            }
        ]
    }    
}
```

then i add this items to the list

```
_rBoxes.addAll(data['box_content']);//it gives error - Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'
```

//widget design

```
ListView.builder(
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: _rBoxItems.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Text("${_rBoxItems[index]}",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0));
                        })
```

Error :
//here i want to loop box_1 index (only) in list view, how to acheive this if i gave
`_rBoxItems['box_1'].length` the error will occur . actucally am stuck in this scenario, help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: `_rBoxes.addAll(data['box_content']);` You want add all to `rBoxes` ?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create `Data` model to parse your json data into a model, `Data` class should look like,

```
class Data {
  BoxContent boxContent;

  Data({this.boxContent});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    boxContent = json['box_content'] != null
        ? new BoxContent.fromJson(json['box_content'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.boxContent != null) {
      data['box_content'] = this.boxContent.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class BoxContent {
  List<Box> box;

  BoxContent({this.box});

  BoxContent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['box'] != null) {
      box = new List<Box>();
      json['box'].forEach((v) {
        box.add(new Box.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.box != null) {
      data['box'] = this.box.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Box {
  String id;
  String name;

  Box({this.id, this.name});

  Box.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Then parse json data into your `Data` model like,

```
import 'dart:convert';  // import this


String jsonData = "{ ... }" // your json as string

Data _data= Data.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonData));
```

Finally you can achieve what you required,

```
ListView.builder(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: _rBoxItems.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Text(_data.boxContent.box[index].length.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
        );
}),
```

Note: You can simply generate models to parse, from json data [here](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to iterate Box Context. If you fetch data from an API firstly you should create your data models and for that you can use app.quicktype.io it is working very well for dart. When I add your Box_1 content to there it gave to me a object like that.
[image]

After creating your data models. You can use this function to get object from json string and you can convert them to a list.
`Box.fromJson(String str) => Box.fromMap(json.decode(str));`

Answer (score 0):

because you're `data['box_content']` is a **Map**, but _rBoxes.addAll needs a **List**, So it's going to report an error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>
```

you should convert `data['box_content']` to **List**, like this:

```
_rBoxes.addAll(data['box_content'].entries.map((entry) => { entry.key, entry.value }).toList());
```

hope helpful ^_^

Comment: yes its cleared the error, but i want to loop only the box_1 object in list view builder, currently it loops full object inside of box_content. @hysunny

Comment: ok~ Actually, it is easy to get `box_1` after you convert **Map** to **List**, you can use `List[0]`.

Comment: u mean this: ListView.builder(itemCount: _rBoxItems[0].length,itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Text(_rBoxItems[0][index].toString());
                        })